# How to set my Django form on the center of the page

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

I have this code in my template:

```
 <form method="post" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
 <table>
 {{ form }}
 </table>
 <input type="submit" class="b1" value="OK"  >
 </form>
```

And I have this in my css file:

```
 table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

In this situation only fields of the form in the center of the page. But the tag input is on the right side of the page. How to connect form fields and input to make them in the center of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your input in a table row.

```
<form method="post" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
<tr colspan=2>
<input type="submit" class="b1" value="OK"  >
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```